# Something weird about express session store

Tags: session, node.js, express, mongoose

If I store an object in session like this:

```
user.name = "Kelvin"; // user is an object pass by "mongoose" findOne's callback.
req.session.user = user; 
console.log(req.session.user.name); // Kelvin
```

and after that, I access "user" in other routes of express:

```
app.get("/somepath", function(req, resp) {
    console.log(req.session.user.name); // undefined
});
```

I want to know why req.session.user.name is undefined besides the function I set it?

Comment: Interesting. What do you get when you call `console.log(req.session.user)`??

Comment: In the function I set the attribute "name", `console.log(req.session.user)` contains other attributes from mongoose and "name" I set, but only attributes form mongoose and no "name" in other routes function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After looking into mongoose source code I can say that this is because how mongoose models and session works. When you call `req.session.user = user` then `req.session.user` points to the object but actually the data needs to be stored somewhere (like memory or Redis).

In order to do that Express calls `JSON.stringify(sess)` and string is stored in memory. Here's where mongoose enters. Models are constructed in such a way, that when you stringify them **only** attributes predefined in Schema are included. So when you set `req.session.user = user` Express stringifies `user` (you loose `name` attribute) and saves the data. When you call `req.session.user` in another route Express parses stringified data and you obtain object without `name` attribute.

Now how to fix this? There are several ways.

- Add `name` attribute to the Schema;
- Define new literal object for user:

  `var newuser = { id: user.id, name : "Kelvin", pwd: user.pwd, etc. };`
  `req.session.user = newuser;`
- Store name in another field: `req.session.name = "Kelvin";` (the best solution imho)

By the way: You shouldn't hold the user object in session. What if some other user like administrator makes changes to the user object? You won't see them at all. I advice holding only the id of the user in session and make custom middleware to load user from DB and store it in `request` object.